# Poor video streaming quality on Ubuntu 20.04

Tags: nvidia, 20.04, graphics, video

I've been trying Ubuntu 20.04 for about 1 month (newbie user alert) and tried to stream some videos using both Amazon Prime Video and Youtube, but the quality is very bad like it is in 480p. Video keeps playing smoothly but in poor quality.

The stream is all set for the best quality available (the same set is used in Windows 10 which OS is in dual boot and the video quality works perfectly) however the image keeps the pixelated appearance. Internet speed looks fine as usual (about 100MB/s) and GPU drivers are up to date. My GPU is an NVIDIA Geforce 1050 Ti Mobile.

Thank you, guys.

Comment: Hey, have you managed somehow this issue?